# Creating a simple mathematics game

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to the javascript developing world and I took it upon myself to create a small game that my fathers students will be able to play at school. This game consists of 4 different mathematical operations (Adding,Subtracting,Multiplication,Division). Once the student clicks on the operation button, they will then be transferred to a new page. This page will have numbers from 1 to 10. This number will be used as a static number. After the user selects this number, they will have 10 different problems to answer. The first number will be a random number from 1 to 12 and the second number will be the digit they selected on the page before. After completing the 10 problems, they will be greeted with a page that will inform them which questions they have missed. I have started the code for the addition part but I ran into several complications.

1) how do i transfer the answer from one function, to another? This will be used to check the input.

2) Will it be more intuitive to use a switch statement in order to select the operation & the static number?

3) Is there any other methods that would facilitate the making of this game?

I would like to thank you in advance and apologize for the long post. I am a bit lost and would love to get some kind of feedback.

```js
var x;

function startAdd() {

  var random = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

    random.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 13));
    //  console.log(random[i]);
  }

  var allRadioButtons = document.getElementsByName("dif");
  var secondNumber;

  for (var i in allRadioButtons) {
    if (allRadioButtons[i].checked) {
      secondNumber = +allRadioButtons[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (var a = 0; a < 1; a++) {

    document.getElementById('probFirst').innerHTML = random[a];
    document.getElementById('probSecond').innerHTML = secondNumber;


    /*
              compareUser();
              function compareUser(){

                if (prob != )
              } */


  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("userNumb").value;
  document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<title>RicoMath - Addition</title>

<body>
  <h1>RicoMath</h1>
  <h1 class="add">Addition</h1>
  <h2>Difficulty</h2>
  <div id="options">
    <div>
      <input id="num1" type="radio" name="dif" value="1">
      <label for="num1">1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="num2" type="radio" name="dif" value="2">
      <label for="num2">2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="num3" type="radio" name="dif" value="3" checked>
      <label for="num3">3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="num4" type="radio" name="dif" value="4">
      <label for="num4">4</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="num5" type="radio" name="dif" value="5">
      <label for="num5">5</label>
    </div>
    <button onclick="startAdd()">Begin!!!!</button>
    <h4 id='probFirst'></h4>
    <h4 id='probSecond'></h4>
  </div>
  <input type="number" id="userNumb" value="">
  <button onclick='myFunction()'>Enter UserNumb</button>
  <p id="Answer"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want the results transferred to a new html page or the same page? Also you say in the text that you will first ask the user to select from 4 types of actions, but the snippet asks to select from 5 numbers?

Comment: @toing_toing I would like the results to be transferred to another page. I have created the buttons for the operations already. I am focusing on creating a working operation before moving on to the next one. I created it up to 5 numbers for testing purposes. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Out of all your questions you have `NO accepted answers`. Please vote on answers and mark helpful ones as the accepted answer...

Answer (score 1):

1) To transfer the data to your next "page", the easy option for you would be to have seperate divs for seperate pages in the same html file. Then when you need to go the the "next page", just show the div you need to show and hide the others.

Here's a the html + pure javascript code for that with a working example:

```
<body>
<div id="page1" style="border-width:2px;border-style:solid">
your first page
<button onclick="showPage2()">Go to Page 2</button>
</div>
<div id="page2" style="border-width:2px;border-style:solid">
2nd page
</div>
<div id="page3">
3rd page
</div>
<script>
showPage1();
function hide(id){
        document.getElementById(id).hidden = true;
    }
    function show(id){
        document.getElementById(id).hidden = false;
    }

    function showPage1(){
    show("page1");
    hide("page2");
    hide("page3");
    }

     function showPage2(){
    show("page2");
    hide("page1");
    hide("page3");
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Here's a [working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mu2r6k6y/)

To transfer your value from the input, just use `document.getElementById()` since you are in the same html document.

2) To get the selected value from the radio button list, just use (as per your code):

```
var rates = document.getElementById('options').value;
```

You can use the same method to get the value from a input box. Please make sure you add a check for empty input and also to check if a  radio button has been selected before getting the value.

I don't see any need to loop as you have done.

3) Definitely learn and use [jquery](https://jquery.com/). It will make your effort much less.

Hope this helps and happy coding!